# Datatables.Net not taking JSON response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, datatables

I am trying to optimise the load of a page that has over 5000 rows of data being returned.

Instead of letting the ASP.Net Webforms code behind produce the HTML I am trying to achieve this using JQuery.

Please see my code below.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TeamChecks.aspx/GetDataTables",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data.d);

                var table = $('#hidJson_tbl_2').DataTable({
                    "ajax": data.d,
                    "columns:": [
                        { "data": "CaseHandlerStaffNumber" },
                        { "data": "RiskProfileText" },
                        { "data": "AssignedCheckerStaffNumber" },
                        { "data": "FeedbackUserStaffNumber" },
                        { "data": "ComplaintRef" },
                        { "data": "ChildComplaintRef" },
                        { "data": "CaseTypeText" },
                        { "data": "CheckGrade" }
                    ]
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
```

which calls method that uses NewtonSoft Json.Net

```
TeamChecks tc = new TeamChecks();

DataTable dtMc = default(DataTable);
dtMc = tc.Get_DatatableFor_GridView(userId, CheckStatusId);

string jsonResult = null;
jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtMc);
jsonResult = jsonResult.Replace("[{", "{data:[{").Replace("}]", "}]}");
return jsonResult;
```

The example I am loosely following because I need to get the values from code behind rather than a text file can be found here https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

The error message that I am getting is

> "{"Message":"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}"

I would be grateful if someone could help me understand where I am going wrong and what I need to do in order to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve, but the bit that sticks out for me is the _"The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property"_ in your error message; seems that your 5000 records are spilling out the side. Sorry if this isn't much help - just thought it might give you a pointer where to go from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the SerializeObject, you have to set maxJsonLength to a big number to suit your case. see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/3771299)

Comment: Thank you, that's got rid of that error and now I have another to work on